# sum range of columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016. Suppose I have columns sales1, sales2,..,sales100 in a dataset, along with some other column, say name.  I want to write a SQL query like

```
SELECT name, SUM(sales1), SUM(sales2),..., SUM(sales100)
FROM dataset
GROUP BY name
```

but I don't believe this is valid SQL syntax.. Is there a shorthand to do this?

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL to generate the query.

Comment: Could you put them in an array, then loop through and add them to find the sum?

Comment: Why do you say that the SQL syntax is invalid?

Comment: He used "...." to indicate range between sales2 and sales100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shorthand, but SSMS provides a simple way to do this.

```
From Object Explorer expand your table and drag the column folder to a query window. 
It will give you a csv list of columns.
```

Oh, but that is not what you wanted!

```
Replace ',' with '), SUM(' and with minor tweaking you can have the desired string.
```

Or you could try this:

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @SQL += 'SUM(' + column_name + '), ' 
FROM information_Schema.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_name = 'mytable' 
AND column_name LIKE 'sales%'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
SELECT @SQL
```

Comment: hmm, that looks interesting. will give that a try - thanks!